# Making dynamically sizing if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to check the columns of a dataframe inside a for loop by using a list, then perform some operations that change the contents of that list for the next iteration. Is it possible to dynamically size the if statement described here.

Example:

```
df = 
a|b|c|d|e
1|2|3|4|5
6|7|8|9|0

check_list = ['a']

for i in range(10):
    if check_list in df.columns:
        do x

        // variable check_list is now equal to ['a','b']
```

so in the first iteration the list only contains 'a' and in the second iteration it contains 'a' and 'b' and then in further iterations it will be changed further. I hope this adequately explains my question.

Comment: so append `'b'` to your `check_list` when you want to increase it. I'm not really clear on your question.

Comment: Would `check_list in df.columns:` even work? AFAIK you can't compare a list to a list unless it's a list of sublists.  Assuming it *somehow works*, you can simply do an `check_list.append()` during your `do x` section like @MooingRawr mentioned.

Comment: No doing an if statement 'check_list in df.columns:' doesn't work that is the crux of my question, if it did then I would just append the extra values to 'check_list' as both of you have recommended here

Answer (score 0):

Working code that might help answer your question:

```
def add_column(l, all_columns):
    """ Example of a function for adding new columns to the check list"""
    if len(l) < len(all_columns):
        return l + [all_columns[len(l)]]
    else:
        return l

all_columns = 'abcde'

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]], columns=list(all_columns))
print(df)

check_list = ['a']    

for i in range(10):

    # issuperset() seems to be the best way to check that the list includes only column names from the dataframe  
    if set(df.columns).issuperset(set(check_list)):
        check_list = add_column(check_list, all_columns) 
        print("checking list:", check_list)

        # do other stuff
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  6  7  8  9  0
checking list: ['a', 'b']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
checking list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I hope this helps.